# i18next html escaped - server side generated emails needing &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, email, translation, i18next

I use i18next to translate email templates. They contain buttons which text need to have `&nbsp;` to prevent bad rendering on smartphone email readers. To prevent smartphone email reader to split the button into two parts, I do need to have no-break-spaces.

The problem is, i18next escapes html.

Instead of `My button`, I got `My&nbsp;button` inside my button.

Here is a simplified version (pseudo code) illustrating what I am trying to achieve:

```
BTN_ACTION = 'My&nbsp;button';

i18n.init(options, function (t) {
    t('BTN_ACTION')
};
```

The jade template looks like:

```
a#btn-create-account(href='url')=t('BTN_ACTION')
```

Comment: Did you try using a Unicode character directly in your source, or its code point? `My\u00A0button`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a Unicode character directly in your source, or its code point, as in `My\u00A0button`.